# Packaging a java application as exe installer with an updatable derby database in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, packaging

I created a java application that uses an embedded derby database in netbeans. I managed to package the application as an exe installer so as to install on other systems. The problem is that when I install on other systems, the application tries to locate the database using the original url (which is on the computer I used in development). How can I solve the problem of packaging so that the database is packaged along with all the required classes of the application?

Comment: Set the Derby Database in your Application/Data folder. Connect with dynamically generated URL. Where is the Data/Derby folder. User install software in various locations. Build the URL dynamically based on the current App location together.

Comment: @moskito-x please permit me to bother you for more details, I have the database folder inside the application folder. I thought I could have the database located at (maybe) the user.home location when the application is installed and then the application could access the database from there whenever its run. Could this relate to building a dynamic URL?

Comment: The URL must point to your App/Data folder not user.home location, So build the URL Dynamic to point to the App/Data folder, where ever  the user has installed the App. Derby Of course must also be installed on the target computer.

Comment: Your JDBC connection URL can be relative or absolute. Perhaps you are using an absolute URL, and a relative URL would make packaging and installation easier?

Comment: @BryanPendleton, indeed I was using an absolute URL. What would a relative URL look like (I mean actual code snippet)?

Comment: @moskito-x, is it possible to simultaneously install Derby while the application is being installed on the target computer, if so, any ideas or leads on how?

Comment: @VictorMenta : Why Not? Read the Derby license. Download the installer and provide it to the user or Install it automatic with your application installer.

Comment: Derby doesn't require any sort of 'install'; it is just a set of jar files, and all you have to do is to include those jar files in your application. That is, Derby is explicitly designed to be embedded into your application, and not be a separately packaged piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe I may have found a way around my problem. I ended up compressing the database folder into a jar file and adding it to the project library of my application. When the application is packaged and installed on another system, I put in a code that creates a directory inside the application folder and another code to extract the contents of the jar file (the database) and place them in the newly created directory.
Only problem I am facing now is what I believe to be a permissions problem because while I am able to create the folder to place the extracted database in, the code to extract the database jar file seems not to be working.